# How to replace jQuery with a different version

Tags: jquery

ASP.NET 3.5

Project uses jQuery v1.2.6 which is included in a master page and I'd like to replace it with different version only on selected pages which use this master.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

As jQuery should be backward compatible, you should not have problem replacing it. But using two different versions on same project sounds like calling for troubles.

Comment: I agree, but this is quite a big project and before it will be replaced there must be done regression tests. I need to use newer version only on couple pages.